# Doesnt run on VS but runs on Dev C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

i have been trying to run this basic program on VS. The code is below

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class student
{
public:
    int id;
    string name;
};
int main()
{
    student s1, s2;
    s1.id = 10;
    s1.name = "ayudh";
    s2.id = 20;
    s2.name =  "pooja";
    cout << s1.id << endl ;
    cout << s1.name << endl;
    cout << s2.id << endl;
    cout << s2.name << endl;
    system("pause");

}
```

when i try to run it i get a error "No operator "<<" matches this operands".
Can someone help me with the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed out

```
#include <string>
```

at the top of the file.